# Sqlite database manual changes are been ignored in queries

Tags: android, sqlite

I have begun to programming in Android with Eclipse a little application who has a tiny sqlite database. As you know, sqlite is really easy to use. I have been using sqlite for many years, but now I have found somethig unusual and disappointing:

- when I try to update manually my database (e.g. using SQLiteman or another SQLite GUI), changes are reflected when I make a simple SELECT * FROM... in SQLiteman. But when I execute my application and make another simple SELECT * FROM... the new row is absent! I doesn't appear!

-I have cleaned my solution and I have tried to update many times with "Import..." without any result.

-I suspect that it may be something related to an internal index not updated, but I'm not sure.

My code is minimal, as you will see:

```
String query = "Select _id, name FROM mytable";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
int totalRows=cursor.getCount();       //<---- This only shows the older total!
```

What's wrong with this?

Addendum:

- I'm not using an emulator and my device is already rooted. But I can't see my database when I go to the DDMS in Eclipse (but this is another question).
- I'm editing the database in my PC and then I import it to Eclipse. I have edited too directly in Eclipse, but without no luck.

Thank you

Comment: Import the latest changed sqlite file

Comment: I've done it, but is still doing the same.

Comment: 1) you can't edit any databases (or files) under your (or any) app on your device unless the device has been rooted

2) you won't be able to do the same on the emulator AFAIK. 

3) What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You need to post more context if you want a better answer. What you have posted is not a real programming question.

Comment: Well, I dont't know if is a programming question because I don't know what happens. I'm going to add some things about it.

Comment: sounds like you are not modifying the database that is on the device... it is unlikely to be an indexing or core SQLite issue

Comment: I have modified it in my PC and then I have imported it to Eclipse. I'm going to edit my post...

Comment: Oh... this is incredible.

As I said before, I don't use the emulator (my PC has several years) and I plug directly my phone to my computer. Well... I have deinstalled my app and rebooted it... Voilá! Now my database runs as I expect. It seems that Jim was nearly in the right way...

Anyway, thank you all for your help. This is a great comunity!

Comment: On last thing: I just have discovered that sqlite databases are not overrided when you update an app in your device (who has an older database). You must use another name for your new database and delete the other. Pffff...

Comment: @aprados Check out my answer it will help you.

Comment: @aprados Your comment should be marked as the answer. Uninstalling alone does not do it. You MUST uninstall and reboot for the changes to be reflected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must be running the older version of your database. Just try to uninstall the old application from the emulator or device and install the new updated version.

I am sure it will reflect.

Whenever you change your database explicitly at that time to get it reflected into application you need to upgrade the version of your database otherwise it will not affect your database. Or you need to uninstall the old version of your application and install updated application that will reflect the SQLite.

Comment: Similar issue here and uninstalling *should* work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, you are not doing a "COMMIT" on the new data, so it isn't persisting in the database in Android